# Android get resource from context's theme programmatically (without direct access to "R")

Tags: android

I split my code into two project to have some kind of SDK with functionalities common to all my future projects.

So I'm having the problem of retrieving values in XML files of one project from the other. For instance, I had to retrieve a color in styles.xml, a custom one (that I defined in attrs.xml, named "iconColor"). Here's what I did:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
int colorIdentifier = context.getResources().getIdentifier("iconColor", "attr", context.getPackageName());
if (theme.resolveAttribute(colorIdentifier, typedValue, true)) {
    return typedValue.data;
}
else {
    return 0;
}
```

and it's working fine from one project to another. Now for another purpose, I wanted to retrieve the colorPrimary of my context's theme. I tweaked my code to have a generic function, here's how it is now:

```
/**
 * Retrieves a resource from context's theme using the resource id
 *
 * @param resId the resource id, ie. android.R.attr.colorPrimary
 * @return the resource value, or null if not found
 */
public @Nullable Integer getResourceFromTheme(int resId) {
    Integer result = null;

    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
    if (theme.resolveAttribute(resId, typedValue, true)) {
        result = typedValue.data;
    }

    return result;
}

/**
 * Retrieves a resource from context's theme using the resource name
 *
 * @param resName the resource name, ie. "colorPrimary"
 * @return the resource value, or null if not found
 */
public @Nullable Integer getResourceFromTheme(@NonNull String resName) {
    int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "attr", context.getPackageName());
    return getResourceFromTheme(resId);
}
```

so that I could, in theory retrieve custom as well as native properties using android.R. However, if it's still working fo my costom iconColor property, I can't retrieve colorPrimary, it's returning incorrect data. Even weirder, I got different values when I try to use one method or the other, which means I got the code wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so the functions are working fine but I made two mistakes, xxxx is a ColorRes and aaaa/bbbb are ColorInt, and I was calling my function with android.R.attr.colorPrimary instead of R.attr.colorPrimary.